# How to extract CouchDB cookie from Httpful response object in PHP?

Tags: php, couchdb, slim-3, httpful

I try to authenticate a user via a RESTful API in combination with CouchDB and Httpful.

The client sends the credentials of the user to my server and the server forwards them to the CouchDB server.

When I `var_dump` the response, I can see that the content is there but I can't extract the cookie which I would like to send back to the client.

**Authenticate function on my Server:**

```
public function authenticate($request, $response)
{             
    $username = $request->getParsedBody()['username']; 
    $password = $request->getParsedBody()['password']; 

    $uri = "http://localhost:5984/_session";

    $sessionToken = \Httpful\Request::post($uri)    
        ->sendsJson()                                 
        ->body('{"name":"'.$username.'", "password":"'.$password.'"}')
        ->send();                                   

    $cookie = $sessionToken->headers->headers[6];

    return $response->withHeader('Set-Cookie', $cookie);
}
```

**The response object:**

```
object(Httpful \ Response) # 56(13) {
    ["body"] => object(stdClass) # 58(3) 
        ...

    ["raw_body"]
        ...

    ["headers"] => object(Httpful \ Response \ Headers) # 57(1) {
        ["headers": "Httpful\Response\Headers": private] => array(6) {
            ...
            ["set-cookie"] => string(85)"AuthSession=abc123; Version=1; Path=/; HttpOnly"
        }
    }

    ["raw_headers"]
        ...

    ["code"]
        ...
}
```

**Error message:**

```
Cannot access private property Httpful\Response\Headers::$headers
```

I would like to know how I could access the `Set-Cookie` attribute with Httpful. I browsed the web on this issue and unfortunately it seems that I'm the only one who is facing this particular problem.

---

**I found a solution:**

I just needed to add these two lines to my authentication controller:

```
$myArray = array_values($sessionToken->_parseHeaders($sessionToken->raw_headers));

$cookie = $myArray[5];
```

The `_parseHeaders` I found within the API documentation from Httpful and played around with it in combination with `array_values`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance of [`Headers`](http://phphttpclient.com/docs/source-class-Httpful.Response.Headers.html)-class is set into `$sessionToken->headers`, that you can just access like an array.

The `set-cookie` header you get with this:

```
$sessionToken->headers['set-cookie'];
```

Comment: I just edited my post and added a solution I found myself. Anyway, your solution looks more nicely because it's just one simple line. I tried `$sessionToken->headers->headers['set-cookie'];` without luck because I thought it is nested. Thank you very much!

Comment: Magiranu: $sessionToken->headers->headers['set-cookie'] doesn't works because the $sessionToken->headers->headers object it's **private** as you can see on the print_r exit.